# ui.bootstrap tooltips stopped working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower, browserify

Can figure out why would that happen. Other directives from ui.bootstrap work: `alert`, `progressbar`, etc. Yet popovers and tooltips for some reason stopped working. Anyone had this problem? I had a problem before - when for some reason default css rule for tooltip was `opacity:0`. But this time a bit different problem. It's not even adding tooltip related stuff to the DOM, as it used to be.

Also I notice from controller of a view where tooltip being used I used to have access to stuff like `tt_title, tt_isOpen, tt_placement`, etc. Now suddenly I can't do that anymore.

I'm suspecting something to do with browserify we're using. I noticed tooltips not working on my computer first, while on my colleague's they still would work, and then he removed bower files and node_modules, cleaned both npm and bower cache, and tooltips and popovers stopped working for him as well.

I've tried adding `ui.bootstrap.tooltip` explicitly as a module dependency, although I already have `ui.bootstrap` listed.

Please, if anyone had similar problems, and know possible solution, help me.

Comment: Why not flag the most popular answer as the correct one? It worked for me and for others.

Comment: @TonyBrasunas because check the date. This question I had long time ago. I am not using Angular anymore. I am not even sure which one is really a correct one. But I'm guessing you're right. I'll mark the popular one as "correct", although it may not be.

Comment: Thanks! And I just used it and it worked, so it's the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating a project from 1.2 to 1.3 and the tool tips stopped working. It seems there is a bug with Angular 1.3. You can read about it here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2828

I fixed the problem by putting some extra attributes on each tool tip:

```
<div tooltip="After today restriction" tooltip-trigger tooltip-animation="false" tooltip-placement="bottom">Hover me</div>
```

Comment: Does ordering matter?

Comment: Ordering should not matter

Answer (score 4):

I am using 1.3.5 and adding

```
tooltip-trigger tooltip-placement="top"
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 1.3.14 and Angular UI Bootstrap 0.11.2, you'll need to include all of the following attributes to make the tooltips work:

```
tooltip="Edit notifications"
tooltip-trigger
tooltip-animation="false"
tooltip-placement="top"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make my tooltips start working again by adding the attribute:

```
tooltip-trigger
```

...and that was all that I needed. I typically use the same attributes on all of my tooltips, aside from the placement which I tend to alter dynamically for responsiveness.

Although the other responses state that you must use `tooltip-placement="top"` or `tooltip-placement="bottom"`, I did not find this to be the case. Each tooltip placement is working for me. I am using Angular 1.4.8.

On each of my tooltips I am using:

```
tooltip-trigger
tooltip-placement="{{tooltip-placement}}"
tooltip="{{tooltip}}"
tooltip-append-to-body="true"
```

Like I said, adding the `tooltip-trigger` attribute made it work for me.

I removed the attribute `tooltip-append-to-body` as a test and my tooltips still work.

In my conclusion, adding `tooltip-trigger` as a attribute is the fix for this.